# Events for closed stream when running jupyter lab in conda env

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am running `jupyter lab 3.5.3`, `Python 3.11.2`, and `conda 23.3.1` through a miniconda installation (python is the miniconda). When running `jupyter lab` in a conda env, I get the following output:

```
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:48.947 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:48.947 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:49.507 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:49.555 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:49.555 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\clm29\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:49.555 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\clm29\miniconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:49.571 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.

  _   _          _      _
 | | | |_ __  __| |__ _| |_ ___
 | |_| | '_ \/ _` / _` |  _/ -_)
  \___/| .__/\__,_\__,_|\__\___|
       |_|

Read the migration plan to Notebook 7 to learn about the new features and the actions to take if you are using extensions.

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate_to_notebook7.html

Please note that updating to Notebook 7 might break some of your extensions.

[I 2023-04-19 21:40:49.571 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:49.571 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\clm29
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:49.571 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 1.23.6 is running at:
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:49.571 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/lab?token=a778091f175f887deeb1503d8fecd290858ecd719e6e391a
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:49.571 ServerApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=a778091f175f887deeb1503d8fecd290858ecd719e6e391a
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:49.571 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2023-04-19 21:40:49.695 ServerApp]

    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/clm29/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-31156-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/lab?token=a778091f175f887deeb1503d8fecd290858ecd719e6e391a
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=a778091f175f887deeb1503d8fecd290858ecd719e6e391a
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:54.147 LabApp] Build is up to date
[I 2023-04-19 21:40:55.944 ServerApp] Kernel started: f60753ff-1e71-45a9-bd5d-62e8276e9f11
This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled
(internal generated filenames are not absolute).
This may make the debugger miss breakpoints.
Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807
```

The kernel I set up for the conda env is idle and won't connect in jupyter lab. I don't think it's because of the python error; I have a hard time seeing why a python debugger issue would prevent the kernel from connecting. The last message I get, which I think may be the issue, is:

```
[W 2023-04-19 21:40:58.130 ServerApp] Got events for closed stream <zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object at 0x00000290C292A800>
```

I don't think the server should have events for a closed stream immediately after starting the server. Can anyone confirm if this is what's preventing my kernel from connecting and what may be the fix?